# While using udf function getting error "Validation$$anonfun$14 cannot be cast to scala.Function5" in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have Scala code where I'm using udf function to calculate calculation and their status in true or false format while executing I'm getting an error like this "cannot be cast to scala.Function5".

Any help will be appreciated.

```
val kdRule = { (st: String, amtIs: Double, sQ: Int, lA: Double, vPP: Double,lD:Double) =>

        if (st != "KL" && st != "AD" && amtIs == 0)

          if (sQ >= 0)

              if (Math.abs(Math.round(lA / sQ)  - Math.round(((vPP * sQ) - lD) / sQ).toDouble ) < 0.02)

                true
              else if (Math.abs(Math.round(lA).toDouble  - Math.round((vPP * sQ) - lD).toDouble ) < 0.02)

                true
              else

                false
              else

                false
        else
          false

      }

      val kdRuleUdf = udf(kdRule)     
      kdDF.withColumn("RowKD", kdRuleUdf(kdDF("stypes"), kdDF("amadv"), kdDF("sdQ"),kdDF("lineM"), kdDF("vPP"),kdDF("lD"))).drop("RowKD")
```

Comment: what is the error now ? I don't see any error with the code.

Comment: Validation$$anonfun$14 cannot be cast to scala.Function5

Comment: this should work i tried in local and its working fine.

Comment: @ShankarKoirala thanks for the input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your UDF, you require 6 arguments and you have passed only 5 parameters.

require:  `val kdRule =  (st: String, amtIs: Double, sQ: Int, lA: Double, vPP: Double, lD: Double)`

Passed `kdRuleUdf(df("stypes"), df("amadv"), df("sdQ"),df("lineM"), df("vPP"))).drop("RowKD")`

Answer (score 1):

Your udf accepts 6 parameters.

```
(st: String, amtIs: Double, sQ: Int, lA: Double, vPP: Double, lD: Double)
```

You are passing only 5.

```
(kdDF("stypes"), kdDF("amadv"), kdDF("sdQ"),kdDF("lineM"), kdDF("vPP"))
```